# What is the difference between ANR and crash in Android?

Tags: android

I have searched on the internet regarding what an ANR is. And I studied those references as well. But I don't get details regarding a crash in Android.

Can someone tell me the difference between ANR(Android not Responding) and a crash in Android?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

ANR stands for **A**pplication **N**ot **R**esponding.

An ANR will occur if you are running a process on the UI thread which takes a long time, usually around 5 seconds. During this time the GUI (Graphical User Interface) will lock up which will result in anything the user presses will not be actioned. After the 5 seconds approx has occurred, if the thread still hasn't recovered then an ANR dialogue box is shown informing the user that the application is not responding and will give the user the choice to either wait, in the hope that the app will eventually recover, or to force close the app.

A crash is when an exception within the app has been thrown which has not been handled. For example, if you try to set the text of an `EditText` component, but the `EditText` is null and there is no try catch statement to catch the exception that your app will crash and will be force closed. The user will not see what caused the crash, they will be shown a dialogue telling that the app has force closed unexpectedly and will give them the option to send a bug report. In this example if you were to look in the bug report you would see the error caused by `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: If you run C++ code via JNI and hit an error there, the app process will simply crash with no dialog for the user. At least it used to.

Comment: If an app is not responding for at least 5 sec then an ANR will occur. But please note that for services the ANR-timeout can be between 10 and 200 seconds depending on the foreground/background mode, see https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/am/ActiveServices.java;l=204

Answer (score 18):

**ANR** (**A**pplication **N**ot **R**esponding) is due to handling a long running task in the main (UI) thread. If the main thread is stopped for more than 5 seconds, the user will get an ANR.

**Crashes** are due to exceptions and errors like NullPointerException, ClassNotFoundException, typecasting or parsing errors, etc. ANR also causes a crash of the application.

Note: Never perform a long-running task on the UI thread.

Reference [**ANR**](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

Comment: Why does a crash occur?

Comment: @user3035740 check the ans now

Comment: Is it possible to find ANR related info in my device?

Comment: if u r getting an crash you can alway find it logcat trace

Answer (score 14):

ANR and Crash Examples:

This question already has an accepted answer, but I am adding 2 simple examples to understand ANR and Crash better.

**ANR:**

```
// this will produce an ANR on your app
int i = 0;
while(true) {
    i++;
}
```

**Crash:**

```
// this will crash your app : will produce java.lang.ArithmeticException
int value = 5, i = 0;
int result = value / i;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Application Not Responding (ANR):**

ANR will display in the following conditions:

- Response to the input event (such as key press or screen touch even) within 5 Sec.
- A Broadcast Receiver hasn’t finished executing within 10 Sec.

How to avoid ANRs?

- Create a different worker thread for long running operations like database operations, network operations etc.

Reinforce Responsiveness: 
In android app usually, 100 to 200 ms is the threshold beyond which user will feel that app is slow. Following are the tips through which we can show application more responsive.

- Show progress dialog whenever you are doing any background work and a user is waiting for the response.
- For games specifically, do calculations for moves in the worker thread.
- Show splash screen if your application has time-consuming initial setup.

**Crash:**
The crash is unhandled condition into the application and it will forcefully close our application. Some of the examples of crashes are like Nullpointer exception, Illegal state exception etc.

Answer (score 2):

ANR stands for Application Not Responding, which means that your app does not register events on the UI Thread anymore because a long running operation is executed there

Answer (score 1):

```
ANR: It is called when anything your application is doing in the UI thread that 
takes a long time to complete (5 sec approx)
```

Reference:    [ANR](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html)

```
Crash: It is called when  your Application gets some Error or Exception raised by the DVM
```

Answer (score 1):

ANR also caused by-

1. No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
2. **A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.**

Answer (score 1):

**ANR stands for Application Not Responding and its occurs when long operation takes place into Main thread......**

**Crash are due to exception and error like Nullpoint,**

Answer (score 1):

ANR stands for **Application Not Responding**.

It can occur due to many reasons like if an application blocks on some I/O operation on the UI thread so the system can’t process incoming user input events. Or perhaps the app spends too much time building an elaborate in-memory structure or computing the next move in the UI thread.

**Blocking the main thread**, won't result in a crash, but a popup will be displayed to let users kills the app after 5 seconds.

But For **Crash**, the main reason is the human errors.
Most of the time an app crashes is because of a coding/design error made by human

Human Errors

Lack of testing

Null Pointer exception

OutofMemory

**Example :**

This is common when a programmer makes a reference to an object or variable that does not exist, basically creating a null-pointer error.

If you have a bad connection, that can also make your apps crash. The app could also have memory management problems.

Please see my answer for the type of android specific exception which may cause the crash.

[Android Specific Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33011319/what-are-the-list-of-android-specific-exceptions/33011695#33011695)

Answer (score 0):

ANR for ex: if You are downloading huge amount data in ui thread, meny other possibilities like insufficient memory etc it will come.. probably it leads to crashes in android , We can't say both are same one follows other

Comment: Where can i find ANR related info?

Answer (score 0):

[ANR and Crash Different][1]
Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by default the “UI thread” or
“main thread”. This means anything your application is doing in the UI thread that takes a long time to complete can trigger the ANR dialog because your application is not giving itself a chance to handle the input event or intent broadcasts.

Answer (score 0):

ANR: Basically due to a long running task on main thread.

There are some common patterns to look for when diagnosing ANRs:

1. The app is doing slow operations involving I/O on the main thread.
2. The app is doing a long calculation on the main thread.
3. The main thread is doing a synchronous binder call to another process, and that other process is taking a long time to return.
4. The main thread is blocked waiting for a synchronized block for a long operation that is happening on another thread.
5. The main thread is in a deadlock with another thread, either in your process or via a binder call. The main thread is not just waiting for a long operation to finish, but is in a deadlock situation.

The following techniques can help you find out which of these causes is causing your ANRs.

**CRASH:**

Reason for crashs can be many. Some reasons are obvious, like checking for a null value or empty string, but others are more subtle, like passing invalid arguments to an API or even complex multithreaded interactions

Answer (score 0):

This is good article at developer portal.
It gives clarity in detail about ANR. 
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html