# What are the list of Android specific exceptions?

Tags: android

I know some of exceptions are thrown by Android framework. Like `ActivityNotFoundException`, `WindowManager.BadTokenException`.

But i am not aware of all other exceptions which are specific to android framework.

Can anybody list possible Android framework specific exceptions with a small description. Or suggest me blogs information which contains the required information.

Comment: Hi Please check the following link to check the common errors:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441049/common-errors-while-writing-android-project

Comment: @RajanBhavsar, Thanks for sharing the link for the information

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html
I think here you can find it, "Known Indirect Subclasses", totally 224 exceptions. 
Only choose the one started by "Android", here are about 72 exceptions, these should be the list

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException
android.accounts.AuthenticatorException
android.os.BadParcelableException
android.util.Base64DataException
android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
android.os.DeadObjectException
android.media.DeniedByServerException
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.InstantiationException
android.opengl.GLException
android.view.InflateException
android.content.IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException
android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException
android.view.KeyCharacterMap.UnavailableException
android.security.keystore.KeyExpiredException
android.security.keystore.KeyNotYetValidException
android.security.keystore.KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException
android.util.MalformedJsonException
android.media.MediaCodec.CodecException
android.media.MediaCodec.CryptoException
android.media.MediaDrm.MediaDrmStateException
android.media.MediaDrmResetException
android.accounts.NetworkErrorException
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
android.util.NoSuchPropertyException
android.media.NotProvisionedException
android.support.v4.os.OperationCanceledException
android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException
android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.FileDescriptorDetachedException
android.os.ParcelFormatException
android.net.ParseException
android.app.PendingIntent.CanceledException
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSDriverException
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSInvalidStateException
android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException
android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException
android.os.RemoteException
android.widget.RemoteViews.ActionException
android.media.ResourceBusyException
android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException
android.database.SQLException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteAbortException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteAccessPermException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBindOrColumnIndexOutOfRangeException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatatypeMismatchException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteFullException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteMisuseException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOutOfMemoryException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteTableLockedException
android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException
android.database.StaleDataException
android.view.Surface.OutOfResourcesException
android.view.SurfaceHolder.BadSurfaceTypeException
android.nfc.TagLostException
android.util.TimeFormatException
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException
android.security.keystore.UserNotAuthenticatedException
android.view.WindowManager.BadTokenException
android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams#token
android.view.WindowManager.InvalidDisplayException
```

Comment: Most of the sub classes are java related only.

Comment: improved, hope the list helps

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is really improved. Will wait for some others response also.