# Android Kill LifeCycle Example

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I was reading about the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) and it says that after `onPause()` and `onStop()` the Activity/Process is killable from the System.

If I have this in `onPause()`:

```
{
    Thread.sleep(20000)
}
```

Is the activity killable in those 20s or after it finishes the `onPause()` method?

Answer (score 2):

If you have that in `onPause()`, you're going to be killed by the watchdog timer and see an [ANR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213482/what-is-the-difference-between-anr-and-crash-in-android) anyway.  `onPause()` and other lifecycle methods need to process quickly. Here's [official documentation on what triggers ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr).

Comment: Okk but regardless of the ANR, if lets say is Thread.sleep(3000) its not killable in those seconds, right ?